# Using Android canvas in different class, debug crash errors

Tags: java, android, canvas

Just starting out with Android, canvas, the works. I have existing Java code that can draw shapes on a graphics object. I am trying to use that code in an Android app with Canvas. Basically, I'm trying to avoid refactoring all of my Java code to use Canvas explicitly. So I'm in the process of making my own "Graphics" object. All it should do is call the appropriate Canvas methods to draw the specified shape.

I've read multiple posts here about not being able to use the canvas object outside of the `onDraw()` method. From what I understand, you can't pass a canvas object to a different class and expect it to work correctly. But I also do not have a complete understanding of how all this works.

The app crashes in the Graphics class in the drawOval method. I've read up a log about all of this, but I haven't found a good answer as to why this specifically doesn't work.
I haven't been able to find a way to get crash logs in a java friendly way (aka a stacktrace). It just throws `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x130 in tid 1520`.

Thanks! Let me know if more details are needed. Here's my code:

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyCanvas canvas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvas = new MyCanvas(this);
        setContentView(canvas);
    }
}
```

`MyCanvas View`

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {
    Graphics graphics;
    List<Shape> shapes;

    public MyCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        graphics = new Graphics();
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        graphics.setCanvas(canvas); //Sets the canvas object in the graphics class
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            try { //this is in a try/catch block for custom exception handling
                //This just calls the specific shapes render method,
                //in this case, a circle from the makeShape Method
                //The graphics object then calls the specific shape to
                //render on the canvas
                shape.render(graphics, 0, 0); 
            } catch (ShapeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                try { //this is in a try/catch block for custom exception handling
                    makeShape(x, y);
                } catch (ShapeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                invalidate();

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                break;
            }
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void makeShape(int x, int y) throws ShapeException{
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        Shape shape = new Circle(p, 50, 50);
        shapes.add(shape);
    }

}
```

`Graphics`

```
public class Graphics {
    private Canvas canvas = null;

    public Graphics() {
    }

    public void setCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        if (this.canvas == null) {
            this.canvas = canvas;
        }
    }

    public void drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawCircle(500, 500, 50, paint1); //App crashes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight misunderstanding about being able to pass a `Canvas` to different classes. There is absolutely nothing wrong with that; passing a canvas to a class method is effectively the same as passing it to a regular function. Even storing the `Canvas` reference in a member variable isn't going to hurt anything.

HOWEVER, the above is only true with the understanding that the `Canvas` cannot be used outside the bounds of the `draw()`/`onDraw()` method. That is, any method that uses the `Canvas` must be called from within `onDraw()`, or a function called by `onDraw()`, etc.

This is because the `Canvas` is initialized (by the framework) immediately before `onDraw()`, in order to prepare for the current drawing operation. You might wish to think of it as initializing the `Canvas` with a `Bitmap` that will serve as the drawing output surface for this particular screen frame (which is not far from the truth). Once `onDraw()` has returned, the framework assumes your code will no longer be using it, and it can submit the output surface/`Bitmap`/etc. to the screen compositor for rendering, without fear of further alterations.

And, your approach is a good one, as a technique for adapting existing code to use a novel graphics object.

So, to address the crash: SIGSEGVs should never happen in normal Android development when you're not dealing (directly) with native/JNI routines. However, it occurs to me that you're not updating the `Canvas` object in the event it changes. *This* could be causing the crash (in native code, which is why you don't get a Java stack trace). You used an old `Canvas` after a newer one was given to you. Remove the condition `if (this.canvas == null)` and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, yeah you definitely confirmed some of the thoughts I had about it. I figured using `Canvas` from somewhere else would cause issues. Basically, the flow goes from my `onDraw` method, to my own Java `Shape` code where there is a render method that takes a `Graphics` object. That graphics object is then used by calling `graphics.drawOval()` as you would with Java awt. Since I can't use that, I'm making my own Graphics class that simply receives the parameters necessary to call a `canvas.drawCircle()`. So other than that, I'm not using any other 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @pianoman102 Sorry, just updated my answer. Please re-read the last paragraph :)

Comment: After some debugging, I know for sure that it's crashing after executing the `canvas.drawCircle()` in my Graphics class.

Comment: oh I see now. So it's a new Canvas object every time `onDraw()` is called? Why and how does that work? That seems like a lot of rerendering to me.

Comment: @pianoman102 I'm unsure of the precise reason the framework provides a different Canvas object each time. But, it's fairly lightweight; just a binding between a `Bitmap` and a `View` (or view tree). Just b/c you're getting a new `Canvas` does not imply there's a lot of re-rendering, but you may be surprised to know that Android does, in fact, re-render the whole view each time even the smallest change is made (generally). Without expounding on that too much, it's because that simplifies `onDraw()` implementations, compositing, alpha mixing, and the details of the hardware-based surface usage.